# Vue component not showing up in my Laravel blade page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**App.js file:**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**blade.php file:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" />
    <script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <title>Chat Deneme</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
        <example-component></example-component>
    </div>

</body>
```

**ExampleComponent.vue :**

```
<template>
    <div>Hello, Example Component!</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name:'example-component',
    mounted() {
        console.log('Example component mounted.')
    }
};
</script>
```

I used npm install --save-dev vue vue-template-compiler to download vue.

**webpack.mix:**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');



mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

I made both npm run watch, npm run dev, npm run hot but there is not error. My page and console is blank.

Comment: I changed <script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>  to  <script src="public/js/app.js"></script> in my blade.php file but now i get this error in console:  Cannot find element: #app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding defer to script tag in my blade.php file and I add default while i was including component in app.js. here is the final app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

// Require Vue
window.Vue = require('vue').default;

// Register Vue Components
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

// Initialize Vue
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```